# How to square a previously squared terms

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to get my term to look like 2^(2^n) and that is how I put it in the code, but it is not working. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use braces for superscripts: `2^{2^{n}}` (of course, in math-mode).

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Answer (score 3):

In `2^(2^n)` TeX would take the first math atom as superscript, rewritten with curly braces:

```
2^{(} 2^{n} )
```

Therefore you need the curly braces for the first superscript:

```
2^{(2^n)}
```

The TeX makes a subformula for `(2^n)` and puts it as superscript for the first `2`.

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
$ 2^{(2^n)} $
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[13pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\(
\displaystyle{2^{2^n}}
\)
\end{document}
```

Produces this 
[image]